# Add and remove class from list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered HTML list such as this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Using jquery, I would like to automatically remove the current class from the first li element and add it to the second class. After a short period of time I would like to remove the class from the second li element and add it to the third. I would like for this to repeat as well.

I have this so far but it's not at all what I need:

```
 $("ul li:first-child").addClass('current').delay(1000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass('current');
    $(this).next().addClass('current')
    next();
});
```

Comment: `.delay()` is specifically used for animations.

Comment: @LittleBigBot: `.delay()` is used for anything queued. That's why OP is using `.queue()` to run the delayed code.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to stop and start it:

```
var myInterval;
var myFunc = function() {
        var cur = $('ul li.current');
        if(cur.index() == $('ul li').length - 1) {
            cur.removeClass('current');
            $('ul li:first').addClass('current');
        } else {
            cur.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        }
    };
//Start Interval
myInterval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

Then, to stop/start:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
myInterval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJgzG/)

Comment: Actually, is there a way to pause the interval on a mouse hover and resume or restart when the mouse leaves?

Answer (score 2):

```
var $li = $('ul li'), i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if( $li.length === i ) i = 0;
    $li.removeClass('current').eq(i).addClass('current')
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mr7J6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var idx = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    $('ul li').removeClass('current').eq(idx).addClass('current');
    idx++;
    if (idx == $('ul li').length) idx = 0;
}, 1000);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QH9gb/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ 
   move();
 });


function move(){
    $("ul li.current").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        if($(this).next().addClass('current').length){
           move();
         } 

     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to wrap around, you can do it using the modulus operator like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var targets = $('ul li');
    var len = targets.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        // remove from current
        $('li.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        i = (i + 1) % len;
        targets.eq(i).addClass('highlight');
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wYJ28/)

Answer (score 0):

Add and remove class unorder list current class using the jQuery click event.
   **

> Working Example

**

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  
      $('.list-1 li').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);
   t.find('a').click(function(){
    $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    t.addClass('current');
   });
   
  });

    });
```

```css
 .list-1 li a{text-decoration:none; color:#444; background:#ddd; padding:5px 15px 10px;}
 .list-1 li.current a{background:tomato; color:#fff;}
  .list-1{display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;min-width:140px}
   .list-1 li{padding:5px;margin:0 0 15px;display:block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
   
    <ul class="list-inline list-1">
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Exapmle 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exapmle 9</a></li>
 </ul>
```